# How to update Joomla custom component?

Tags: mysql, joomla, components, joomla3.0

I'm trying update my custom component which I had created.

The version number when I installed was 0.0.1. Later on I had to do some changes in the table (had to add a column). So I changed the version number to 0.0.2 and I created a sql file with name 0.0.2.sql.

But when I try to update in extension manager. ie, extension -> manage -> discover -> clicked on discover button. it didn't show my component.

How do I update the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the component is already installed then whatever changes you make to files wont display under discover, unless you are changing the folder names. Better to change the version in xml and add the sql file, zip your component and reinstall it. Remember to have `method="upgrade"` in your xml file.

Comment: Do we need to upload the full component files and folders again?
is there a easy way to update the component and sql files?

Comment: @ManojKumar What I used to do is i) Make all the changes necessary in the files and database. 2) Create a log file in notepad. 3) Unzip my main component 4) Overwrite the changes to the admin and site folders, Change the version number in xml file  5) ZIp it again 6) and send it to my viewers.